# Polymorphism with a dereferenced pointer yields unexpected results...why?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, visitor-pattern

I've run into a C++ conundrum and could use some help!
Please consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    virtual void print() 
    {
        std::cout << "Node::print" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Drawable : public Node
{
    virtual void print() 
    {
        std::cout << "Drawable::print" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void apply(Node& node)
    {
        std::cout << "apply(Node&)" << std::endl;
        node.print();
    }
    virtual void apply(Drawable& drawable) 
    {
        std::cout << "apply(Drawable&)" << std::endl;
        drawable.print();
    }
};

struct Renderer
{
    virtual void accept(Node* node, Visitor* visitor)
    {
        visitor->apply(*node);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Renderer r;
    Visitor v;
    Drawable* drawable = new Drawable();
    r.accept(drawable, &v);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
apply(Node&)
Drawable::print
```

I was expecting Visitor::apply(Drawable&) to be invoked, but instead apply(Node&) is invoked. Why?

Comment: `I was expecting Visitor::apply(Drawable&) to be invoked` Why? You're calling `apply` with a `Node*`, not with a `Drawable*`.

Comment: Function overload resolution doesn't care about dynamic type. It just looks at the static type of the arguments provided.

Comment: Your visitor pattern is wrong. The way you've done it you do not need visitor at all. Visitor is used when you need double dispatch pattern.

Comment: SergeyA, it's a simplified version of visitor pattern from an [open source SDK](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/include/osgUtil/CullVisitor#L110) that does use double-dispatch (I think). I just wanted to keep the question simple :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this line of code:

```
virtual void accept(Node* node, Visitor* visitor)
{
    visitor->apply(*node); // <--- Here
}
```

When the compiler sees this call to `apply`, it needs to determine whether you meant to call the version of `apply` that takes in a `Node&` or the version of `apply` that takes in a `Drawable&`. Notice that this is a decision about which **overload** to pick rather than which **override** to pick. Decisions about overloading are made at compile-time. Here, the compiler looks at the expression `*node` and says "well, `node` is a `Node *`, so `*node` is a `Node&`" because it can't know at compile-time what the runtime type of the thing pointed at by `node` is. As a result, this will always call `apply(Node &)` and will never call `apply(Drawable&)`.

This explains what's going on, but how do you fix it? The conventional way to get the visitor pattern set up is to place a function like this one at the base of the class hierarchy:

```
struct Node {
    virtual void accept(Visitor* visitor);
};
```

You'd then have every subclass of `Node` override that function. Each override would then look something like this:

```
struct Pizkwat: Node {
    virtual void accept(Visitor* visitor) override {
        visitor->apply(*this);
        // do more things, optionally
    }
};
```

In the line of code in this override, the type of `*this` will at compile-time be the same type as the object in question. That means that **overload** selection will pick the version of `apply` most specific to this type.

To use this `accept` function, you can write something like this:

```
virtual void accept(Node* node, Visitor* visitor)
{
    node->accept(visitor);
}
```

Now, think about what happens. The `accept` member function is marked `virtual`, so the specific version of `accept` to call depends on the type of the thing pointed at by `node` (that is, it uses the *dynamic type* rather than the *static type*). This is using **override** resolution rather than **overload** resolution. That will then call into the proper override, which, as you saw above, then selects the proper **overload**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is `Pizkwat`?

Comment: Great explanation @templatetypedef - accepting. My real challenge is that I have to work with a library that's already designed this way -- so now that I understand whay's happening I can find a workaround. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @SergeyA It's a throwaway word that doesn't mean anything. I like it more than `Foo` or `Bar`. :-)